# html2canvas and jspdf genereted blank pdf

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

Hi i created [invoice page](https://instamarketing.pl/cennik/faktura?order_code=4lbbctnc) and added to them jsPDF and html2canvas, but my solution generated blank pdf. How can I repair this? where is a bug ?

In my project used jspdf and html2canvas, can you help me with this?

Script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
        function generatePDF() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [1380, 2030]);
 
            html2canvas($(".page-section")[0], {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                    var width = canvas.width;
                    var height = canvas.clientHeight;
                    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 20, 20, (width - 10), (height));
 
                }
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
 
                pdf.save('sample.pdf');
                var blob = pdf.output("blob");
                var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var iframe = document.getElementById('sample-pdf');
                iframe.src = blobURL;
                var downloadLink = document.getElementById('pdf-download-link');
                downloadLink.href = blobURL;
            }, 0);
 
 
        };
        generatePDF();
 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://instamarketing.pl/cennik/js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://instamarketing.pl/cennik/js/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div class="page-section">

test

</div>
```